# proof $z \mid b$ and $w\mid b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, quadratics

Question I'm working on: Let $a,b$ be integers with $b$ not equal to $0$. suppose $x^2+ax+b=0$ and $x=z,w$. If $z,w$ are integers, show that $z\mid b$ and $w\mid b$.

Is it sufficient for me to show that $x^2+ax+b=(x-z)(x-w)$ so $b=zw$?

Comment: "suppose $x^2+ax+b=0$ and $x=z,w$" is not clear. Probably you mean "$x^2+ax+b=0$ _for_ $x=z,w$", in other words $x^2+ax+b=0$ holds when $x=w$ and also when $x=z$. If it is _in addition_ given that $z\neq w$ then you may conclude that $x^2+ax+b=(x-z)(x-w)$, since a quadratic polynomial can have only two distinct roots. But as written, the case $z=w$ is not excluded; in that case you are just given the same information twice, and you cannot decompose $x^2+ax+b$. It turns out there is an argument that works for that case too, handling $z$ and $w$ independently of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $w$ and $z$ are solution of the equation $$x^2+ax+b=0$$ we have
$$w^{2}+aw+b=0 \Rightarrow b=-w(w+a) \Rightarrow w|b$$

In the same way for $z$.

Regards!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better approach:

We need to show $z|b$ and $w|b$.  What does it mean for $z$ to "divide" $b$?  It means there is some integer $k$ such that $z \cdot k = b$.  Well, what are we given?  We are given that if $x = z$ or $x = w$, then $x$ satisfies $x^{2} + ax + b = 0$.

But that means $z^{2} + az + b = 0$, or $z^{2} + az = -b$.  But then that means $z(z + a) = - b$.  Since $z + a$ is an integer (because $z$ and $a$ are integers), then we have found an integer $k$ such that $z \cdot k = -b$, so $z$ divides $-b$.  Is it clear that if $z$ divides $-b$, then $z$ divides $b$?

You can use the same argument for $w$.  Does this argument make sense to you?  Do you understand every step?

Comment: it does and I do. thank you for the help